# How to convert Ledger seed to Monero compatible seed on Windows?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, windows, ledger

My Ledger HW is broken and I can’t access my funds. I have my Ledger seed but I can’t enter it in Monero wallets. How do I convert the seed?

Comment: I followed instructions and have had to edit paths to add python script to windows environment which worked and pip installed but now I am stuck on the last command.
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/src python -m ledger.monero.seedconv.py offline I get a permission denied when I try.
it shows the path under my user name and the python program then says permission denied.
What did I do wrong or what do I need to do to get permission granted?

Comment: @RandalTurner Did you make sure to follow the instructions exactly? Did you start the git bash as admin?

Comment: I did everything and got to the final part, after PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/src python -m ledger.monero.seedconv.py offline, I typed in "2" hit enter, nothing happened, I typed in yes and hit enter and nothing happened, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Entering your seed on your computer can potentially expose it to malware if your computer is compromised.

---

First step is to download `Git for Windows`.

- Go to [gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org) and use the Download button.
- Install it with default settings.

Next step is to install Python 3.

- Go to [python.org](https://python.org) and download the latest `Python 3 Windows x86-64 executable installer`. I used the following link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/python-3.8.1-amd64.exe
- Open the installer, select `Add Python 3.8 to PATH` and then install with default settings.

Afterwards open the `git-bash` shell the following way.

- Open the following path: `C:\Program Files\Git` in Explorer.
- Start `git-bash.exe` as administrator, maximize the window.

Then enter the following commands, line by line.

- `pip3 install pycryptodomex ECPy ledgerblue pyreadline`
- `git clone https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero`
- `cd ledger-app-monero/tools/python/`
- `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`
- `` PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/src  python -m ledger.monero.seedconv.py offline ``

Now the program should have started successfully. To confirm the seed language, enter `2` for English. Then enter `yes` and it will ask you for your 24 word Ledger seed. Your Monero compatible seed should finally show up now.